# Modifique un datafile, pero en el SO sigue teniendo el mismo espacio. SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Hola gente tengo el problema que he modificado un datafile:

```
use master

ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE
(NAME = 'tempdev', SIZE = 10240)
```

Pero dentro del SO en la ruta el archivo sigue ocupando el espacio anterior, porque ocurre esto??}
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

una aclaración con este tema, ya que al usar :

```
ALTER DATABASE con MODIFY FILE
```

para cambiar el tamaño de un datafile solo funciona si se quiere aumentar el tamaño del datafile [ALTER DATABASE File and Filegroup Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx) .

Si lo que quieres hacer es achicar el tamaño del datafile, lo que debes hacer es usar el comando

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE
```

Siempre y cuando dentro del data file tengas espacio libre, aqui esta la referencia de uso [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189493%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

De todas formas lo que sucedió en tu caso si verificaste una disminución en el tamaño del datafile despues de reiniciar la instancia, es que al tratarse de la base de sistema tempdb , esta se recrea en cada reinicio de la instancia de SQL server, asi que quizas el datafile de esta base te quedo muy grande por algunas operaciones costosa de ordenamiento, group by, etc.. ,ejecutaste el comando

```
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE
(NAME = 'tempdev', SIZE = 10240)
```

para achicarla, no paso nada y cuando reiniciaste esta base se recrea al tamaño original, pero lo qque la achico fue este comportamiento de la tempdb y no la ejecucion de tu comando .

Espero haya servido.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola gente respondiéndome a mi mismo para que se vean efectivos los cambios tuve que reiniciar la instancia.
Si se aumenta el tamaño del datafile no hay necesidad de reiniciar la innstancia.
Saludos